# ¿Cómo crear un salto de línea en un placeholder de un <textarea>?

Tags: html, html5

Necesito hacer un salto de linea en un placeholder de un textarea.
Pero solo con HTML.

¿Cómo crear un salto de línea en un placeholder de un textarea?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], considera agregar lo que llevas al momento

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con `&#10;` como salto de línea:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>PLACEHOLDER TEXTAREA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Ejemplo PLACEHOLDER TEXTAREA</h1>
    <textarea placeholder="ESTE&#10;ES&#10;UN&#10;PLACEHOLDER"></textarea>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si mal no me equivoco, con `&#10;` puedes hacer un salto de linea, por ejemplo

```
placeholder="Linea 1 &#10; Linea 2 &#10; Linea 3".
```

Tambien podrias hacerlo en javascript, con setAttribute y usando \n